# Periodic 4D Triangulations

Tags: algorithms, reference-request, computational-geometry, simplex

I am looking for references and/or algorithms for generating 4-dimensional periodic triangulations on unit 4 lattices. That is, generating a space filling triangulation of the 4D integer lattice (Z^4) that is invariant under lattice translations. I have found references for 2D and 3D, but it is not clear to me how to generalize these to 4D.

Comment: Could you add links to the 2D/3D references that you found? 
Where these related to z-order/Morton-order or Hilbert curves?